# Shortcuts in HANA studio SQL Console/SQL Editor

Tags: hana, hana-studio

In SAP HANA Studio (ver 2.2) there is a so called "SQL Console" where you can write your SQL code (sometimes also called "SQL Editor").

There are some keyboard shortcuts to improve productivity with this tool. What I found:

- <kbd>F8</kbd>: execute Query
- <kbd>F9</kbd>: execute Query where Cursor is (Query means SQL statement separated by semicolon)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>: execute "Explain Plan for " + Query where Cursor is
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>: toggle between SQL and result window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>: toggle between Editor windows (sometimes also Alt+Cursorkey)
- <kbd>F2</kbd>: clear the Editor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>: format the Query
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>: Undo
- <kbd>AB</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>: autocomplete (where AB are the first two letters of the statement or object)

Are these the only shortcuts in SQL Console? Is there a way to start the SQL console by shortcut? Is there a way to connect by shortcut? Is there a way to use HANA studio without a mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HANA Studio is an Eclipse application (more precisely a whole bunch of Eclipse plug-ins).

That means, keybindings are handled by Eclipse and you can use the `Help` - `Show Active Keybindings` menu action to get a list of all the currently active "shortcuts".

Generally speaking, HANA Studio is meant as a visual tool and mouse usage is largely required. 
However, you can define your own keybindings (e.g. for the "Open SQL Console" command) in the Eclipse preference settings.

Comment: Do you mean: Ctrl-Shift-L what opens Help/Key Assist... ? Only some few shortcuts used within SQL Console are shown here.

Comment: Then you can still look in the already mentioned preferences setting.

Comment: Unfortunately these shortcuts seem to mostly only work outside SQL Console: i.e. How to 'uppercase' something?

Comment: I’m pretty sure to have answered your questions. But ok, let’s have another one... afaik there is no uppercase command in the HANA SQL console editor and thus no shortcut for it either.